# add an option to change embedded vimeo video through links on my page

Tags: html, vimeo, vimeo-player, embedded-video

This is a screenshot of what I have

[image]

now under Gigi and Bob I have 5 song links.
I would like to link these directly to the vimeo player in my page
so that when for example a user clicks on the "Silence" song link under Gigi the video will go to this song.

The current html for the song list under Gig is

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">L'Amour</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bla Bla Bla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Riddle</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another Way</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Silence</a></li>
</ul>
```

and for the vimeo video it is

```
<section id="player">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/105778399" width="200" height="150" frameborder="1" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to play a video you have the embed url for then you can target your links to the `iframe`. You just need a `name` attribute on your iframe and `target` attribute on the links:

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sx3wwLba/)

```
<a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/45196609?autoplay=1" target="VimeoPlayer">L'Amour</a>

<section id="player">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/105778399" name="VimeoPlayer" width="200" height="150" frameborder="1" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</section>
```

If you want something more complicated there's an API that allows you to integrate the Vimeo player into your website using JavaScript: https://github.com/vimeo/player.js

Comment: Nice and clear solution, thank you for this! I didn't actually now that you can change iframe source by links with pure HTML. Would've gone for the jQuery to solve this. Have to keep this in mind. :)

Comment: This is a brilliant answer and works perfectly, nice one on the "never going to give you up" link. Cheers